# Changing the order by results depending on column value?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort a column by the lowest value, BUT if the value is `0` then I want all columns with that value placed at the end and NOT the start.

Can this be done?

Just say query is currently..

```
SELECT * FROM auctions ORDER BY a.discount_start_date ASC
```

Is there a method where I can do what I want?

Comment: Your `discount_start_date` can be 0?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes it can - if the item doesn't have a discount.

Comment: May be you have confused 0 with `null`? Is the `discount_start_date` of type `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No I have not confused it, it's value is `0`, not `NULL` and it's an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ORDER BY FIELD` on column `a.discount_start_date`.

**Example**:

```
SELECT * FROM auctions 
ORDER BY FIELD( a.discount_start_date, '0000-00-00'), a.discount_start_date;
```

All the records that have a zero date in `discount_start_date` column are placed last and rest are sorted in ascending order and placed on top.

**Refer to**:
[*MySQL: FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Comment: Do you know if this has any advantages over simons answer with using CASE?

Comment: As there is only case of `0` date, there is no difference. But use of `field` is simple compared to multiple `case when then` handling.

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement in the order by, such that if the value is 0, set it to the maximum possible value for that field, else return the value of the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM auctions 
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN a.discount_start_date = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CASE DESC,
  a.discount_start_date ASC;
```

I suggests that you use appropriate data type for your data.

Comment: Thanks. It stores the data as a UNIX TIMESTAMP so that's why it's stored as an integer. :)